# I want to copy data from another workbook to my current workbook using vba code

Tags: excel, vba

I want to write a code similar to UDF where I hardcode a function and then create parameters for it for the code below. This is for opening an excel file and from external workbook and copy pasting the values from certain columns to the active workbook.

Private Sub Btn_Load_Test_Data_file_Click()
Dim FileLocation As String
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim wb As Workbook
Set wb = ActiveWorkbook

```
FileLocation = Application.GetOpenFilename
If FileLocation = "False" Then
    Beep
    Exit Sub
End If

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Set ImportWorkbook = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=FileLocation)
LastRow = ImportWorkbook.Worksheets("Projects").Range("A7").End(xlDown).row
curr_lrow = wb.Worksheets("Projects").Range("A5").End(xlDown).row

'Copy range to clipboard
ImportWorkbook.Worksheets("Projects").Range("B7", "B" & LastRow).Copy
'PasteSpecial to paste values, formulas, formats, etc.
wb.Worksheets("Projects").Range("A" & LastRow).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues

ImportWorkbook.Worksheets("Projects").Range("C7", "C" & LastRow).Copy
wb.Worksheets("Projects").Range("C" & LastRow).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues

ImportWorkbook.Worksheets("Projects").Range("D7", "D" & LastRow).Copy
wb.Worksheets("Projects").Range("E" & LastRow).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues

ImportWorkbook.Worksheets("Projects").Range("E7", "E" & LastRow).Copy
wb.Worksheets("Projects").Range("F" & LastRow).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues

ImportWorkbook.Worksheets("Projects").Range("F7", "F" & LastRow).Copy
wb.Worksheets("Projects").Range("G" & LastRow).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues

ImportWorkbook.Worksheets("Projects").Range("G7", "G" & LastRow).Copy
wb.Worksheets("Projects").Range("H" & LastRow).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues

ImportWorkbook.Worksheets("Projects").Range("H7", "H" & LastRow).Copy
wb.Worksheets("Projects").Range("I" & LastRow).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues

ImportWorkbook.Worksheets("Projects").Range("I7", "I" & LastRow).Copy
wb.Worksheets("Projects").Range("J" & LastRow).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues

ImportWorkbook.Worksheets("Projects").Range("J7", "J" & LastRow).Copy
wb.Worksheets("Projects").Range("K" & LastRow).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues

ImportWorkbook.Worksheets("Projects").Range("K7", "K" & LastRow).Copy
wb.Worksheets("Projects").Range("L" & LastRow).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues

ImportWorkbook.Worksheets("Projects").Range("L7", "L" & LastRow).Copy
wb.Worksheets("Projects").Range("M" & LastRow).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues

ImportWorkbook.Worksheets("Projects").Range("M", "M" & LastRow).Copy
wb.Worksheets("Projects").Range("N" & LastRow).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues

ImportWorkbook.Worksheets("Projects").Range("N7", "N" & LastRow).Copy
wb.Worksheets("Projects").Range("O" & LastRow).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues

ImportWorkbook.Worksheets("Projects").Range("O7", "O" & LastRow).Copy
wb.Worksheets("Projects").Range("P" & LastRow).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues

ImportWorkbook.Worksheets("Projects").Range("P7", "P" & LastRow).Copy
wb.Worksheets("Projects").Range("Q" & LastRow).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues

ImportWorkbook.Worksheets("Projects").Range("Q7", "Q" & LastRow).Copy
wb.Worksheets("Projects").Range("R" & LastRow).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues

ImportWorkbook.Worksheets("Projects").Range("R7", "R" & LastRow).Copy
wb.Worksheets("Projects").Range("BL" & LastRow).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues

ImportWorkbook.Worksheets("Projects").Range("S7", "S" & LastRow).Copy
wb.Worksheets("Projects").Range("BM" & LastRow).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues

ImportWorkbook.Worksheets("Projects").Range("T7", "T" & LastRow).Copy
wb.Worksheets("Projects").Range("BN" & LastRow).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues

ImportWorkbook.Worksheets("Projects").Range("U7", "U" & LastRow).Copy
wb.Worksheets("Projects").Range("BO" & LastRow).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues

ImportWorkbook.Worksheets("Projects").Range("V7", "V" & LastRow).Copy
wb.Worksheets("Projects").Range("BP" & LastRow).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues

ImportWorkbook.Worksheets("Projects").Range("W7", "W" & LastRow).Copy
wb.Worksheets("Projects").Range("BQ" & LastRow).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues

ImportWorkbook.Worksheets("Projects").Range("X7", "X" & LastRow).Copy
wb.Worksheets("Projects").Range("BR" & LastRow).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues

ImportWorkbook.Worksheets("Projects").Range("Y7", "Y" & LastRow).Copy
wb.Worksheets("Projects").Range("BS" & LastRow).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues

ImportWorkbook.Worksheets("Projects").Range("Z7", "Z" & LastRow).Copy
wb.Worksheets("Projects").Range("BT" & LastRow).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues

ImportWorkbook.Worksheets("Projects").Range("AA7", "AA" & LastRow).Copy
wb.Worksheets("Projects").Range("BU" & LastRow).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues

ImportWorkbook.Worksheets("Projects").Range("AB7", "AB" & LastRow).Copy
wb.Worksheets("Projects").Range("BV" & LastRow).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
```

End Sub

Comment: Hi, your paste range should be the same size as copied range. Your Range("A"+LastRow) returns only 1 cell.

Comment: @bracko - no that's not required.  You can paste to a single cell no problem.

Comment: Did you mean `Range("B7", "B" & LastRow)` or maybe `Range("B7:B" & LastRow)` ?  The first one is just two cells, and the second is all cell between Rows 7 and `LastRow`.  Also you need to paste after each copy - you can't do 2 copies and then 2 pastes....

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```vb
Private Sub Btn_load_data_file_Click()
    
    Dim FileLocation As String
    Dim LastRow As Long, wsPaste As Worksheet, curr_lrow As Long
    Dim wb As Workbook, ImportWorkbook As Workbook, wsImport As Worksheet
    
    FileLocation = Application.GetOpenFilename
    If FileLocation = "False" Then
        Beep
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
    Set wsPaste = wb.Worksheets("Projects")
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Set ImportWorkbook = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=FileLocation)
    Set wsImport = ImportWorkbook.Worksheets("Projects")
    
    LastRow = wsImport.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1 'safer than .End(xlDown)...
    curr_lrow = wsPaste.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1
    
    CopyValues wsImport.Range("B7:B" & LastRow), wsPaste.Range("A" & curr_lrow)
    CopyValues wsImport.Range("C7:C" & LastRow), wsPaste.Range("C" & curr_lrow)
    
    ImportWorkbook.Close False
   
End Sub

'Copy values from `rngFrom` to `rngTo`
Sub CopyValues(rngFrom As Range, rngTo As Range)
    With rngFrom
        rngTo.Cells(1).Resize(.Rows.Count, .Columns.Count).Value = .Value
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Do you know how to create a function in VBA and call that function for copying and pasting data.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean - any Function/Sub can copy/paste.  If you mean a function called as a UDF from a worksheet cell, then that type of action is restricted.

Comment: yes I mean if a UDF can be created and then used for different set of codes. Because the file I am copying from can have different format too, so I dont want to go to all codes and then change everything, instead I have to change only the UDF.

Comment: You can't use a UDF for that, but you can have a main code which is driven by smaller methods which pass the required parameter values to that main code.  Difficult to suggest anything more specific without some actual examples.

Comment: Oh I see, okay let me try something like that, thanks Tim

Comment: Do you have an idea about the main code and then small methods, I am not able to come to conclusion with any such ideas

Comment: I have no way to know what type of variability you need to be able to handle.   There’s only one sub posted so I can’t generalize from that.

Comment: oh, okay, wish I had an option to inbox you

Comment: You can always edit your question to add code or details there...  Then if I have time this week I can take a look.

Comment: I have edited my question and code, please have a look when you get time.